# Can't get MDDropdownMenu and MDDropDownItem to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, kivy, kivymd

Whenever I press on the  MDDropDownItem the Menu opens but when I select an option nothing happens

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.dropdownitem import MDDropDownItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class Contents(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.langlist =MDDropDownItem(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})
        self.langlist.text = 'English'
        self.add_widget(self.langlist)
        self.langlist.bind(on_release=self.menuopen)


        self.langlistmenu = MDDropdownMenu(caller=self.langlist,items=[{'viewclass':'MDMenuItem','text':'English'},{'viewclass':'MDMenuItem','text':'Arabic'}],width_mult=3)
        self.langlistmenu.bind(on_release=self.menuclose)
    def menuclose(self,instance_menu,instance_menu_item):
        print(instance_menu_item.text)
        print(instance_menu)
        self.langlist.set_item(instance_menu_item.text)
        self.langlistmenu.dismiss()


    def menuopen(self,instance):
        self.langlistmenu.open()

class AndroidApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        #self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Red'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = 'A400'
        return Contents()

AndroidApp().run()
```

Comment: Have a look at the `MDDropDownMenu` property [callback](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/menu/index.html#kivymd.uix.menu.MDDropdownMenu.callback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it

Here's the code:

```
 from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.dropdownitem import MDDropDownItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class Contents(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.langlist =MDDropDownItem(pos_hint={'right': 0.85, 'top': 0.98})
        self.langlist.set_item('English')
        self.langlist.md_bg_color = [1,1,1,1]
        self.add_widget(self.langlist)
        self.langlist.bind(on_release=self.menuopen)


        self.langlistmenu = MDDropdownMenu(position='bottom',callback=self.menuclose,caller=self.langlist,items=[{'viewclass':'MDMenuItem','text':'English'},{'viewclass':'MDMenuItem','text':'Français'},{'viewclass':'MDMenuItem','text':'Deutsche'},{'viewclass':'MDMenuItem','text':'русский'},{'viewclass':'MDMenuItem','text':'Español'}],width_mult=4)

    def menuclose(self,instance):
        self.langlist.set_item(instance.text)
        self.langlistmenu.dismiss()


    def menuopen(self,instance):
        self.langlistmenu.open()

class AndroidApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        #self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Red'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = 'A400'
        return Contents()

AndroidApp().run()
```